# How to securely detect accounts with matching passwords?

Tags: hash, cryptography, security, bcrypt

On our message board, we use password matching to help detect members with multiple registrations and enforce our rules against malicious puppet accounts. It worked well when we had SHA256 hashes and a per-site salt. But we recently had a humbling security breach in which a number of password hashes fell to a dictionary attack. So we forced a password change, and switched to bcrypt + per-user salts.

Of course, now password matching doesn't work anymore. I don't have a formal education in cryptography or computer science so I wanted to ask if there's a secure way to overcome this problem. Somebody I work with suggested a second password field using a loose hashing algorithm which intentionally has lots of collisions, but it seems to me that this would either lead to tons of false positives, or else reduce the search space too much to be secure. My idea was to stick with bcrypt, but store a second password hash which uses a per-site salt and an extremely high iteration count (say 10+ seconds to generate on modern hardware). That way users with the same password would have the same hash, but it couldn't be easily deduced with a dictionary attack.

I'm just wondering if there's an obvious problem with this, or if someone more knowledgeable than me has any suggestions for a better way to approach things? It seems to me like it would work, but I've learned that there can be a lot of hidden gotchas when it comes to security. :P Thanks!

Comment: Might want to try asking for suggestions on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

Any algorithm that would allow you to detect whether or not 2 users had the same password would also allow an attacker to detect whether or not 2 users had the same password.  This is, effectively, a precomputation attack.  Therefore, your problem is not securely solvable.

### Example

- Assume I've compromised your password database.
- Assume I've figured out how your hashes are calculated.

If I can apply your password transformation algorithm to "password" and quickly tell which users use "password" as their password, then the system is vulnerable to a form of precomputation attack.

If I must do an expensive calculation to determine the password for each individual user and work spent to calculate User A's password does not make calculating User B's password easier, then the system is secure (against these type of attacks).

### Further Consideration

Your idea of using a per-site salt with bcrypt and a high iteration count may seem attractive at first, but it just can't scale.  Even at 10 seconds, that's 6 password guesses per minute, 360 per hour, 8640 per day, or 3M per year (that's a lot).  And that's just one machine.  Throw a botnet of machines at that problem, or some GPU's and suddenly that number goes through the roof.  Just 300 machines/cores/GPU's could knock out 2.5M guesses in a day.

Because you would be using the same salt for each one, you're allowing the attacker to crack all of your user's passwords at once.  By sticking with a per-user salt only, the attacker can effectively only attempt to crack a single user's password at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughtful response. It makes intuitive sense the way you explain it. I guess we may have to forgo this functionality in the interest of security. I really appreciate your taking the time to help clear this up for me!

Comment: @YthanBurstein No problem.  It's a very interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer given above makes the assumption that the attacker has the same access  as the server at all times, which is probably not reasonable. If the server is compromised in a permanent manner (owned by the attacker) then no scheme can save you - the attacker can retrieve all passwords as they are set by the user. The model is more normally that an attacker is able to access your server for a *limited* period of time, some point after it has gone live. This introduces an opportunity to perform the password matching that you've asked about without providing information that is useful to an attacker.

If at sign-up or password change your server has access to the password in plain text, then the server could iterate through all the user accounts on the system, hashing the new password with each user's individual salt, and testing to see if they were the same.

This doesn't introduce any weaknesses, but it would only be useful to you if your algorithm for preventing multiple fake accounts can use this as a one-time input ("this password matches these accounts").

Storing that information for later analysis would obviously be a weakness (for if an attacker can obtain your database of passwords, they can probably also obtain this list of accounts with the same password). A middle ground might be to store the information for daily review - reducing the total useful information available to an attacker who temporarily compromises your storage.

All of this is moot if the salting and hashing occurs client-side - then the server can't carry out the test.

Comment: Wow, thank you! You make several excellent points that I hadn't ever considered. Like most elegant solutions, the idea about hashing a new password against existing salts and saving data about matches seems totally obvious in retrospect, but I never would have thought of it on my own. If anyone else is struggling with the same issue, I encourage them to pursue this idea. It seems like the best possible compromise.

Comment: You make a good point that you could iterate over each user's account and check for duplicates, though depending on the number of users that may take up more CPU (and clock) time than desired.  However there are 2 key problems in what you stated. 1. While an attacker does typically only have access for a limited period of time, it doesn't take long to download the password database.  Then they can attempt cracking forever after that.  2. Salting and hashing should **never** occur on the client side.  Any input from the client can be spoofed or otherwise manipulated.  That is not secure.